# Where can I ask for a definition?

Tags: support, tags, questions

I'm looking for a way to ask for the definition of a word I heard somewhere: an "isoproduction" database.

So I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to ask it on StackOverflow or not, and what are the tags I'm supposed to use.

Comment: Without any more context, so if your question literally is _"What is an isoproduction database"_, it's not on-topic.

Comment: Ask on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) I guess

Comment: Anyway, a quick Google search leads me to believe that the "iso" prefix means "equal," as in isometric, "having equal measurements.", and a search for "isoproduction" shows that it's a term used in agriculture, to determine whether the yields of a certain area are up to par with comparable areas. An "isoproduction database" would hence be a database in which the production of farmland is stored, along with its measurements. But I might be off by miles.

Comment: This sounds like a nonsense word, the kind created by adding a prefix to a word to make yourself sound impressive or important, but utterly failing at the primary point of language: clear communication. If Google doesn't turn up any meaningful results, chalk it up to meaningless drivel and move on.

Comment: Considering `"isoproduction" database` appears in 0 hits, I'd guess that it either doesn't exist, or it's a bastardization of `ISO FileMaker` which has something to do with FileMaker, a FoxPro/access style database-backed application maker.  Which sucks all the balls.  Considering I learned all this from the first page of hits in my favorite search engine, this question would be (essentially) off topic everywhere on SO because of lack of research.